# Find dates that fail to parse in R Lubridate

Tags: r, date, lubridate

As a R novice I'm pulling my hair out trying to debug cryptic R errors. I have csv that containing 150k lines that I load into a data frame named 'date'. I then use lubridate to convert this character column to datetimes in hopes of finding min/max date.

```
  dates <- csv[c('datetime')]
  dates$datetime <- ymd_hms(dates$datetime)
```

Running this code I receive the following error message:

```
Warning message:
3 failed to parse.
```

I accept this as the CSV could have some janky dates in there and next run:

```
min(dates$datetime) 
max(dates$datetime)
```

Both of these return NA, which I assume is from the few broken dates still stored in the data frame. I've searched around for a quick fix, and have even tried to build a foreach loop to identify the problem dates, but no luck. What would be a simple way to identify the 3 broken dates?

```
example date format: 2015-06-17 17:10:16 +0000
```

Comment: You can check whether the format is consistent.  Also check `?guess_formats`

Comment: If you sort on the datetime vector, would the NA's be either at the head or the tail?

Comment: @akrun I attempted to do this in excel by import csv and checking the length of each cell and filtering for anything out of place. This didn't result in anything, is there a way to do this in R? I've attempted guess_formats & parse_date_time and both have failed.

Comment: @lawyeR That was it! I sorted the unparsed raw csv, then tail(dates) displayed the three incorrect fields. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could also find the row numbers of the missing dates with `which(is.na(dates$datetime))`.

Comment: @Stibu this is exactly what I was looking for, quick and easy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Credit to LawyeR and Stibu from above comments:

1. I first sorted the raw csv column and did a head() & tail() to find
   which 3 dates were causing trouble
2. Alternatively `which(is.na(dates$datetime))` was a simple one liner to also find the answer.

Comment: This is great, but doesn't really answer the general question. What if the problem is that the character 'purpleElephant' is in your data? It's not an NA yet is still unparseable. We still need some way to view the warnings that are given by Lubridate.

Comment: The question was about identifying the three broken dates and this accomplishes that perfectly.

Comment: But it only accomplishes that because the 3 dates happened to be NAs. I have a vector of 93 dates/datetimes which contains ~17 NAs and am getting "2 failed to parse". So this solution doesn't solve the generic problem, just the problem in OP's case.

Answer (score 4):

Lubridate will throw that error when attempting to parse dates that *do not exist* because of daylight savings time.

For example:

```
library(lubridate)
mydate <- strptime('2020-03-08 02:30:00', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ymd_hms(mydate, tz = "America/Denver")

[1] NA
Warning message:
 1 failed to parse.
```

My data comes from an unintelligent sensor which does not know about DST, so impossible (but correctly formatted) dates appear in my timeseries.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple function that solves the generic problem:

```r
parse_ymd = function(x){
  d=lubridate::ymd(x, quiet=TRUE)
  errors = x[!is.na(x) & is.na(d)]
  if(length(errors)>0){
    cli::cli_warn("Failed to parse some dates: {.val {errors}}")
  }
  d
}

x = c("2014/20/21", "2014/01/01", NA, "2014/01/02", "foobar")
my_date = lubridate::ymd(x)
#> Warning: 2 failed to parse.
my_date = parse_ymd(x)
#> Warning: Failed to parse some dates: "2014/20/21" and "foobar"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Of course, replace `ymd()` with whatever you want.

Comment: It eliminates the failure warning but it does not show where the failure happens if there is a lot of data (I changed options(max.print = .Machine$integer.max) to avoid printing limitation however still the message does not appear ). It solved my problem.

Comment: Using this function I was able to determine that I had an impossible date of ```2000-11-38``` which I fixed and no longer had the parse failure.

Answer (score 1):

If the indices of where lubridate fails are useful to know, you can use a for loop with stopifnot() and print each successful parse.

Make some dates, throw an error in there at a random location.

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(1)
my_dates<-as.character(sample(seq(as.Date('1900/01/01'), 
as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 1000))
my_dates[sample(1:length(my_dates), 1)]<-"purpleElephant"
```

Now use a for loop and print each successful parse with stopifnot().

```
for(i in 1:length(my_dates)){
   print(i)
   stopifnot(!is.na(ymd(my_dates[i])))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To provide a more generic answer, first filter out the `NA`s, then try and parse, then filter only the `NA`s. This will show you the failures. Something like:

```
dates2 <- dates[!is.na(dates2$datetime)]
dates2$datetime <- ymd_hms(dates2$datetime)

Warning message:
 3 failed to parse.

dates2[is.na(dates2$datetime)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the truncate argument. The most common type of irregularity in date-time data is the truncation due to rounding or unavailability of the time stamp.

Therefore, try truncated = 1, then potentially go up to truncated = 3:

```r
  dates <- csv[c('datetime')]
  dates$datetime <- ymd_hms(dates$datetime, truncated = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

ludridate::ymd_hms() expects a certain number (usually 19) of characters when it attempts to parse a timestamp string. Sometimes, timestamps that fall at midnight are rendered as just the date portion, meaning the string has only 10 characters. There are other reasons such as simple data errors that may result in a non-standard string length but NA-based operations won't find these.

To see if you have some anomalies in string lengths, you can use

`table(nchar(dates$datetime))`

If you find entries with problem strings, you can identify the rows using

`which(nchar(dates$datetime) != 19)`